# Angular filter does not update the view after model update

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a custom filter, here is my test view to probe it:

```
<div>{{ 1400956671914 | userDate }}</div>
<div>{{ 1288323623006 | userDate }}</div>
```

This is based on angulars filter and sets the users date format based on his own preferences:

```
app.filter('userDate', function ($filter, userModel) {

  var userDate = userModel.getPreferences().dateFormat;
  // userDate = 'yyyy-mm-dd'

  function userDateFilter (date) {
    return $filter('date')(date, userDate);
  };

  return userDateFilter;

});
```

This is the result:

```
2014-05-24
2010-10-28
```

I have a view where I update the model userModel and set the dateFormat as 'dd/mm/yyyy' then I return to my test view and it remains the same:

```
2014-05-24
2010-10-28
```

I have to press f5 to see the expected changes:

```
24/05/2014
28/10/2010
```

How can I listen the change in the model to update the filter?

Comment: Maybe the controller is cached, try to set `cache:false`in your route state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userDate` format is captured in the function `userDateFilter`. It won't be changed if the user preferences change. What you want is to fetch the user date format when the filter is executed. Try:

```
app.filter('userDate', function ($filter, userModel) {

  function userDateFilter (date) {
    return $filter('date')(date, userModel.getPreferences().dateFormat);
  };

  return userDateFilter;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you changing the model? I:n some cases you'll want to wrap it in an angular $timeout() for it's affect to take place the next cycle. Try to avoid the $apply() trap.